# Get a folder path where is missing specified file into variable

Tags: batch-file, directory, detect

Let's say I have **two** folders **in one**.

**MyFolder\Folder1\ - contains *.class* and *.java* file**

**MyFolder\Folder2\ - contains only *.class* file**

The question is, if you can make the batch file detect the folder in (MyFolder) where is a .java file missing and put the path into a variable.

***Something like:***

find sub/folder with no *.java files in MyFolder\   <-and somehow to put the folder path into a variable

Does anyone know what would the script look like?
Thanks to everybody that will help.

Comment: Are you sure this has to be DOS and not Windows?  DOS does not even support 4-letter filename extensions.

Comment: it doesn't really have to be a DOS batch file......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea, you can work on it to make it suit your needs:

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /D %%f in (MyFolder\*) do if not exist %%f\*.java (
    set nonJavaFolder=%%f
)
echo !nonJavaFolder!
```

Comment: You can try CDing into MyFolder, searching `in (*)`, and then CDing one level up.

Comment: Ah, another happy customer.

Comment: I forgot.. I actually wanted it like this:
for /D %%f in (MyFolder\*) do if exist %%f\*.class >BUT< if not exist %%f\*.java


 - But in one line/command - 
(Like the first script you wrote - for /D %%f in (MyFolder\*) do if not exist %%f\*.java echo %%f)

Comment: Okay, stack the ifs.  `if not exist X ( if exist Y ( ...` and then on the next line `)` and one line further down one more `)`.

Comment: I'm having a problem...
as you told me the code:

for /D %%f in (MyFolder\*) do if not exist %%f\*.java echo %%f

now it says %f instead of the path

Comment: Are you trying to execute that code outside of the batch file?  When typing commands directly to the command prompt, use %f.  When writing commands in a batch file, replace with %%f.

Comment: I already fixed it xD
I just edited it:

for /D %%f in (MyFolder\*) do set path=%%f & if exist ......

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*" '
  ) DO (
  IF NOT EXIST "%sourcedir%\%%a\*.java" ECHO no .java IN "%sourcedir%\%%a"
  IF NOT EXIST "%sourcedir%\%%a\*.class" ECHO no .class IN "%sourcedir%\%%a"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

Naturally, you could set a variable instead of `echoing` the result. You don't say what you want to do if there is more than one directory with missing files.