# Copy files specified files with subfolders to another folder[BATCH]

Tags: batch-file

This question is related to this: [Get a folder path where is missing specified file into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384875/get-a-folder-path-where-is-missing-specified-file-into-variable) a little bit...

I have one empty folder and a second folder where is another folder and in there are some .class files

```
Myfolder1\Folder1 - contains the class files
Myfolder2\ - empty
```

I tried this:

```
set path=%%f        (the variable from the last question) 
xcopy %path%\*.class Myfolder2\ /s
```

It's like this:

```
xcopy Myfolder1\Folder1\*.class Myfolder2\ /s
```

What need is to copy the class files into the second folder including the subfolder, so the second folder should look like this:

```
Myfolder2\Folder1\\[the class files]
```

Does anybody know? (the code does not need to be using Xcopy)

Thanks to all that'll help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
XCopy Myfolder1\*.class Myfolder2\ /S /I /Y
```

By starting your copy at the parent level (`Myfolder1`) and specifying the `/S` switch, you are telling the command to look in subfolders when determining what to copy. When your `.class` files are found in a subfolder, the respective folder will be created in your destination (`Myfolder2`).